# FlutteBloc:r BlocListener doesn't trigger state changes

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have 2 views/widgets:

- View Items
- Add New Item

When I add a new Item successfuly (logic is handled inside MyBloc), I trigger the state **MyStateAddItemSuccessful** which sends me back to **'View Items'** screen.

I monitor the state changes inside **'Add New Item'** with the following listener:

```html
BlocConsumer<MyBloc, MyState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is MyStateAddItemSuccessful) {
                // Navigate to 'View Items' view 
              }
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return SubmitBtn(
                btnTxt: 'Save',
                onTap: () => createItem(context),
              );
            },
          ),
```

**The problem is,** whenever I go back to 'View Items' view and then into 'Add Item' view, the state remains the same - meaning BlocListener won't trigger any state changes!

The obvious solution would be to change the state when I enter 'View Items' view, but it can get really tedious when adding multiple views.

What would be a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the state stays there? As far as I understand you use the same Bloc for two views, right

Comment: Yeah, 1 Bloc for 2 views.

Comment: Where you create the BlocProvider ? What changes do you expect in the view Add New Item ? like reset the Bloc, reset State, reset what ?

Comment: My BlocProvider is inside the main (the widget above 'View Items'), the changes i expect inside 'Add New Item' are to reset the state so that when I go to 'View Items' (when pressing the Submit button), and then back into 'Add New Item', the state won't remain as 'MyStateAddItemSuccessful', but some default state

Comment: If you just, just, just want to change one state to another, what you can do is at the end of your event where you Submit, change the state, or always when you enter the Add New Item view, change to another state, such as Initial

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! So in that case, I'd have to trigger some 'Initialize' bloc event inside initState of my 'Add New Item' view? (which would then trigger the 'Initialize' state inside MyBloc), or can I emit the state directly somehow? (Sorry for the dumb question, this is new to me!)

Comment: Don't worry, it's good to have doubts, because if you want that View to be reset at startup, as you don't have an event that chains that state, you can create an InitialEvent, you call it in the initState or also before doing Push to the Add New Item.

Comment: But if you already have an event created that does some kind of logic, you can only do an emit(InitialState()) at the beginning or in the end of that event before pushing to the View Items, but if not, then create a custom event in the initState.